# R graphics: Add labels to stacked bar chart

Tags: r, label, bar-chart, stacked

I am looking for a way to add labels, i.e. absolute values, into a stacked bar chart using the basic plot functions of R. The labels should be inside the stacked bars.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`barplot` will return the mid x position of the bars, so you could do

```
mydata <- matrix(c(10, 21, 22, 33, 45, 23, 22, 43, 33), nrow=3)

# b will contain the x midpoints of the bars
b <- barplot(mydata)

# This will write labels in the middle of the bars, horizontally and vertically
text(b, colMeans(mydata), c("Label1", "Label2", "Label3"))

# This will write labels in the middle of the middle block
text(b, mydata[1,]+mydata[2,]/2, c("LabelA", "LabelB", "LabelC"))
```

**EDIT:** re-reading your question, I think this is what you want (or maybe not, but I'll write it anyways :D)

```
# Find the top y position of each block 
ypos <- apply(mydata, 2, cumsum)
# Move it downwards half the size of each block
ypos <- ypos - mydata/2
ypos <- t(ypos)

text(b, ypos, mydata)
```

Comment: Hi Nico,  wow this works perfectly fine with vertical barplots. Thank you very much. I´m glad that the solution was not that mysterious. I also tried to apply your code to a vertical barplot as well. Simply exchanging b and ypos does the trick. Many many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about the simple function `text()`?

You can simply add a string where ever you want, eg:

```
text (x = ..., y = ..., labels = c("foo bar 1000"))
```

Comment: text was also my first choice, but how can I tell R that it should place the values from my dataset within the centre of the stack itself?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use or inspect the **barp** function of the [plotrix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotrix/index.html) package