# R graphics: add labels to clustered/dodged bar chart

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

This is a basic plotting question:

I need to add labels to a clustered/dodged bar chart. I have looked at several examples using `text()`, but cannot seem to position the labels correctly.

```
teachers <- c("A", "B","C", "D", "E")
mean_pre_scores <- c(10, 11, 12, 10,9)
mean_post_scores <- c(12,15,17,13,12)
pre_post <- data.frame(mean_pre_scores, mean_post_scores)

pre_post <- as.matrix(pre_post)
barplot((t(pre_post)), beside = T, names = teachers, legend = c("pre", "post"), 
        ylim = c(0,20), args.legend = list(x="bottomright"),  axes = T, main = "Unit 1 Test",
        col=c(26,51))
```

I want to modify this plot so that the values will be displayed above the bars. It would also be helpful to know how to show the values inside the bars.

Comment: This [post] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626324/r-graphics-add-labels-to-stacked-bar-chart) discusses the same issue, you might have to tinker with Y-position of the labels for your dataset

Comment: @Vivek Yes, I saw this post, but am having trouble positioning the labels.

Comment: I posted solution on similar lines as the above link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
z <- barplot((t(pre_post)), beside = T, names = teachers, 
    legend = c("pre", "post"), ylim = c(0,20), 
    args.legend = list(x="topright"),  axes = T, 
    main = "Unit 1 Content Pre Test", col=c(26,51))

text(cex=1, x=c(z[1, ], z[2, ]), y=c(pre_post) + par("cxy")[2]/2, c(pre_post), xpd=TRUE)
```

[image]

To move the text inside the bars simply use subtractions as in:

```
text(cex=1, x=c(z[1, ], z[2, ]), y=c(pre_post) - par("cxy")[2]/2, c(pre_post), xpd=TRUE)
```

Comment: Can I suggest moving the legend up top?

Comment: @Richard agreed, I did so.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "above the bars", do you mean directly above them?  Or on the top axis?

Here's an example with them on top.

**And now** it's clear you wanted the numeric values on the bars instead of the letters on the top axis.  I'll leave it here anyway, and post a second result below.

```
> barplot((t(pre_post)), beside = T, legend = c("pre", "post"), ylim = c(0,20),
          args.legend = list(x="bottomright"),  axes = T, col=c(26,51))
> axis(3, at = c(2, 5, 8, 11, 14), labels = teachers)
> title(main = "Unit 1 Content Pre Test", line = 3)
> box()
```

[image]

Here's the correct result. I moved the legend to the top right corner where it won't be covering any bars.  A bit easier to read that way.

```
> barplot((t(pre_post)), beside = TRUE, legend = c("pre", "post"), 
          main = "Unit 1 Content Pre Test", ylim = c(0,20), 
          args.legend = list(x="topright"), col=c(26,51))
> text(x = c(1.5,2.5,4.5,5.5,7.5,8.5,10.5,11.5,13.5,14.5), 
       y = txt.height+1, labels = as.character(txt.height))
> box()
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm we interpreted this differently but I definitively get you're thinking.  I guess the OP will have to clarify.

Comment: I think you got it.  She did say "values".  I ran right past the meaning of that.

Answer (score 1):

A `ggplot2` solution:

```
# get the data into the right format
pre_post <- data.frame(teachers,mean_pre_scores, mean_post_scores)
library(reshape2)
prepost <- melt(pre_post, id = "teachers")

# create the plot
ggplot(prepost, aes(x = teachers, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), vjust = -0.5, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  theme_bw()
```

the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from this post ([R graphics: Add labels to stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626324/r-graphics-add-labels-to-stacked-bar-chart))

For inside labels:

```
teachers <- c("A", "B","C", "D", "E")
mean_pre_scores <- c(10, 11, 12, 10,9)
mean_post_scores <- c(12,15,17,13,12)
pre_post.df <- data.frame(mean_pre_scores, mean_post_scores)

pre_post <- as.matrix(pre_post.df)
b<-barplot((t(pre_post)), beside = T, names = teachers, legend = c("pre", "post"), 
     ylim = c(0,20), args.legend = list(x="bottomright"),  axes = T, main = "Unit 1 Content Pre Test",
     col=c(26,51))


ypos.inside<-apply(pre_post, 2, function(x) x -1 )
ypos.inside <- t(ypos.inside)

text(b, ypos.inside, pre_post)
```

[image]

For outside labels:

```
teachers <- c("A", "B","C", "D", "E")
mean_pre_scores <- c(10, 11, 12, 10,9)
mean_post_scores <- c(12,15,17,13,12)
pre_post.df <- data.frame(mean_pre_scores, mean_post_scores)

pre_post <- as.matrix(pre_post.df)
b<-barplot((t(pre_post)), beside = T, names = teachers, legend = c("pre", "post"), 
     ylim = c(0,20), args.legend = list(x="bottomright"),  axes = T, main = "Unit 1 Content Pre Test",
     col=c(26,51))

ypos.outside<-apply(pre_post, 2, function(x) x +1 )
ypos.outside <- t(ypos.outside)
text(b, ypos.outside, pre_post)
```

[image]

Comment: This approach is less generalizable than the one I provide in that if the scale becomes extreme (change one number to something like 100) the relative label placement changes.