# Create a stacked area plot or "stacked" circle plot

Tags: r, bar-chart, stacked, stacked-area-chart

**Purpose**

Create a stacked area plot or a "stacked" circle plot (see picture). Pie chart is not desired.

**Data and code of a bar plot**

```
#Data set:
Numbers     16%
Frosts       2%
Doors        6%
Shelfs      10%
Earning     -3%

par(mai=c(2, 1, 1, 1), lwd=2)
barplot(as.numeric(c(16, 2, 6, 10, -3)), col = c("lightblue"), main="Bar plot",
        names.arg=c("Numbers","Frosts","Earning", "Doors","Shelfs"), xpd=TRUE, las=2, lwd=2, 
        axes=FALSE, axis.lty=1, cex.axis=1, cex.names=1, cex.main=1, ylim=c(-4, 18), xlim=c(0, 5))
```

**Two output options**

[image]

Comment: how do you propose to plot negative values in a circle plot?

Comment: The negative values (neg) are plotted positive |neg| but all near to the center and e.g. in red. Also a text should show e.g. -3% and the name like the example above

Comment: Using mdata <- matrix(nrow=5, ncol=1, c(-3, 2, 6, 10, 16))
barplot(mdata, col = c("lightblue"), main="Bar plot",
        xpd=TRUE, las=2, lwd=2, axes=FALSE, axis.lty=1,
        cex.axis=1, cex.names=1, cex.main=1); creates a stacked bar plot without text. But using func `text()` I do not have any idea how to add text which will be placed always at the center of each area or on top or bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you most of the way there

```
library(ggplot2)
df<- data.frame(value=as.numeric(c(16, 2, 6, 10, -3)),
                cat=c("Numbers","Frosts","Earning","Doors","Shelfs"))

ggplot(df[order(df$value),], aes(x=1, y=abs(value), fill=factor(ifelse(value>0, 0, 1)))) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="grey") +
    geom_text(aes(label=paste(cat, value)), position = "stack", vjust = 3) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "red"))
```

[image: Bar Plot]

```
ggplot(df[order(df$value),], aes(x=1, y=abs(value), fill=factor(ifelse(value>0, 0, 1)))) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="grey") +
    geom_text(aes(label=paste(cat, value)), position = "stack", vjust = -1) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "red")) +
    coord_polar()
```

[image: Circle Plot]

You may need to fiddle around with the vjust values to change the position of the labels, or calculate a custom y mapping for them, but it's a good start.

Comment: Is there a ability to hatch the areas with grey lines with some angles similar to `barplot`? With barplot(..., col=c(...), density=NUM, angle=c(....),....) you can set the colors, density and the angles of the different hatchings.

Comment: Not easily. This link includes some hacks to make it happen, but it looks like a lot of effort: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895319/how-to-add-texture-to-fill-colors-in-ggplot2

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be very hard :D workaround. Maybe I will use only some grey colors.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to work with this:

```
library(ggplot2)
data<-data.frame(Name=c("Earning","Frosts","Doors","Shelfs","Numbers"),Val=c(1,2,6,10,16))

ggplot(data,aes(x=factor(1),y=Val,fill=Name))+
geom_bar(stat="identity",width=1)+coord_polar()
```

Just change color palette and add text wherever you want (and of course first value in `Val` column if it's too big on the plot - it corresponds to your negative value)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [topmost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626324/r-graphics-add-labels-to-stacked-bar-chart?rq=1) of the "Related" links to the right should give you most of the info you need to construct a stacked bar plot, but adapted for your use it would be something like this:

```
# A vertical matrix containing the values
md <- matrix(c(-3, 16, 2, 6, 10), ncol=1)
d <- barplot(md, col=c(2, rep(0, 4))) 

# Finding the vertical position for the labels
ypos <- apply(md, 2, cumsum)
ypos <- ypos - md/2
ypos <- t(ypos)

# I haven't checked if the values and names match
text(d/3, ypos, adj=c(0, NA),
  paste(c("Earning","Numbers","Frosts","Doors","Shelfs"), md, sep=": "))
```

[image]