# Strange 'X' in front of every x-axis label (year)... How to remove?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I have a yearly x-axis 1998-2014. As you can see on the picture below, in front of every year is an 'X'

[image]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVz7b.jpg)

How can I remove this?

I also want written every year vertical below every bar. And the values of every bar in the red and green part visible...

I wrote this code:

```
    d=read.delim("LW_Einkommen.csv", sep=";", dec=".", header=TRUE, row.names=1)
str(d)

da=data.matrix(d, rownames.force = NA)
da

barplot(da,
        main="ø Einkommen CH Landwirtschaftsbetriebe 1998-2014",
        xlab="Jahr",
        ylab="Einkommen pro Betrieb [CHF]",
        ylim=c(0, 100000),
        col=c("red","green"),
        cex.axis = 0.9, cex.lab = 0.9)

grid(col="black")

legend("bottomleft",
       c("Landwirtschaftliches Einkommen","Ausserlandwirtschaftliches Einkommen"),
       fill=c("red","green"))
```

Comment: Will help a lot if you provide the first few lines of your dataset.

Comment: The labels have come from the column names of your dataset. Numeric column names automatically have an X appended. Try using the `names.arg` argument to `barplot` to set the names

Comment: Check the `las` argument to `par` to make the labels vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you R. Telford for the 3 very important imputs for me!
With this, further threads here and whole day tinkering, I'm almost done with it.

Other Possibility is adding to the `read.delim` line `check.name=F`:

```
d=read.delim("LW_Einkommen.csv", sep=";", dec=".", header=TRUE, row.names=F)
```

Just one little mistake (I marked the label-part bolt) is in my script, leading to a wrong order of block-labeling in my stacked barplot, as you can see in the picture below:
[wrong block-labeling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3KIb.jpg)

Acutal order begins 98red through all red blocks and jumps than to the green blocks...
But it should be one bar from red to green after the other...

```
d=read.delim("LW_Einkommen.csv", sep=";", dec=".", header=TRUE, row.names=1)
str(d)

da=data.matrix(d, rownames.force = NA)
da

bp=barplot(da,
        main="ø Einkommen CH Landwirtschaftsbetriebe 1998-2014",
        xlab="Jahr",
        ylab="Einkommen pro Betrieb [CHF]",
        ylim=c(0, 100000),
        las=3,
        col=c("red","green"),
        cex.axis = 0.9, cex.lab = 1, cex.names=0.9,
        names.arg = expression("1998","1999","2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006",
                               "2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014"))

**# Find the top y position of each block 
ypos <- apply(da, 2, cumsum)
# Move it downwards half the size of each block
ypos <- ypos - da/2
ypos <- t(ypos)
text(bp, ypos, da, cex=0.7)**

grid()

legend("topleft",
       c("Landwirtschaftliches Einkommen","Ausserlandwirtschaftliches Einkommen"),
       fill=c("red","green"),cex=0.9)
```

The template for labeling I took from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3627269/6467646